# Vim, how to play without the beeps?

Tags: vim

I have started to like coding while listening to music. However this means I can't use vim with the sound off.

It seems I get a beep when I press escape, or press `:`

I'm on a Mac, and I love vim and now love listening to music at the same time.

How can I use vim so I don't make these mistakes -- or can I just disable beep from the terminal? Why does vim beep so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have [you tried adding](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_beeping) the following to your .vimrc?

```
set noerrorbells visualbell t_vb=
if has('autocmd')
  autocmd GUIEnter * set visualbell t_vb=
endif
```

**Hint:** Vim Wikia is almost always the best place to look for Vim tips

Answer (score 3):

```
set belloff=all
```

worked on Ubuntu 18.04, vim-gtk3 8.0.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589352/how-to-disable-vim-bells-sounds

Comment: This worked great for me on, VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2, Homebrew 2.5.0, macOS Catalina 10.15.6 on 12 Sep 2020.